# Concatenate values of two keys in the same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I had a dictionary like:

```
a = {'date' : ['2012-03-09', '2012-01-12', '2012-11-11'],
     'rate' : ['199', '900', '899'],
     'country code' : ['1', '2', '44'],
     'area code' : ['114', '11', '19'],
     'product' : ['Mobile', 'Teddy', 'Handbag']}
```

Then I used zip function to concatenate the values:

```
data = [(a,b,c+d,e) for a,b,c,d,e in zip(*a.values())]
```

Output:

```
data = [('2012-03-09', '199', '1114', 'Mobile'),
        ('2012-01-12', '900', '211', 'Teddy'),
        ('2012-11-11', '899', '4419', 'Handbag')]
```

What if I want the function to itself search for the 'country code' and 'area code', and merge them. Any suggestions please?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? Dictionaries do not have a fixed order, so your `zip()` function is not going to give you the values in a predictable order to concatenate.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters -- I think you are very near to understand what I actually want :) what I am trying to say is that I don't want to use zip function and what if I don't know the length of dictionary? that is why I want a piece of code which can itself search for the key names and values in the dictionary and whenever it finds the 'Country code' and 'Area code', it may merge them.

Comment: But what does merging mean in this case? Store it in a new key? Deletes the old keys? We need a little more info here.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters -- I want the Same output as defined in my question but I want to do it in generic way, don't want a hard code for it! Hope to get some help from you :) Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Without knowing what ordering you expect, making this generic *doesn't make much sense*. What does `data[0][0]` *mean*? What key supplied that column? So, at the very least an ordering needs to be specified. And if you need to specify an ordering, then you can also specify what columns might need merging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic method to merge 'columns', letting you specify what columns to expect and what to merge up front:

```
def merged_pivot(data, *output_names, **merged_columns):
    input_names = []
    column_map = {}
    for col in output_names:
        start = len(input_names)
        input_names.extend(merged_columns.get(col, [col]))
        column_map[col] = slice(start, len(input_names))
    for row in zip(*(data[c] for c in input_names)):
        yield tuple(''.join(row[column_map[c]]) for c in output_names)
```

which you call with:

```
list(merged_pivot(a, 'date', 'rate', 'code', 'product', code=('country code', 'area code')))
```

passing in:

- the list of mappings
- each columns that makes up the output (`'date', 'rate', 'code', 'product'` in the above example)
- any column in the output that is composed of a merged list of input columns (`code=('country code', 'area code')` in the example, so `code` in the output is formed by merging `country code` and `area code`).

Output:

```
>>> list(merged_pivot(a, 'date', 'rate', 'code', 'product', code=('country code', 'area code')))
[('2012-03-09', '199', '1114', 'Mobile'), ('2012-01-12', '900', '211', 'Teddy'), ('2012-11-11', '899', '4419', 'Handbag')]
```

or, slightly reformatted:

```
[('2012-03-09', '199', '1114', 'Mobile'), 
 ('2012-01-12', '900', '211', 'Teddy'),
 ('2012-11-11', '899', '4419', 'Handbag')]
```

Instead of calling `list()` on the `merged_pivot()` generator, you can also just loop over it's output if all you need to do is process each row separately:

```
columns = ('date', 'rate', 'code', 'product')
for row in merged_pivot(a, *columns, code=('country code', 'area code')):
    # do something with `row`
    print row
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the order of keys yourself (otherwise `a.values` returns it in an arbitrary order). I renamed your original dictionary to `dd`:

```
[(a,b,c+d,e) for a,b,c,d,e in zip(*(dd[k] for k in ('date', 'rate', 'country code', 'area code', 'product')))]
```

returns

```
[('2012-03-09', '199', '1114', 'Mobile'),
 ('2012-01-12', '900', '211', 'Teddy'),
 ('2012-11-11', '899', '4419', 'Handbag')]
```